# Find a textbox based on string and change its Text

Tags: c#, xaml

I did this in C# -

```
 foreach (Control ctl in this.groupBox3.Controls)
        {
            if ((ctl is Textbox) && (ctl.Name.Substring(0, 1) != "l"))
            {
                Textbox tmp= (Textbox)ctl;
                tmp.text = "whatever";
```

Im trying to do something similar in WPF but this time i want to find the textbox based on a string.

So I tried

```
TextBox temp = (TextBox).Findcontrol("txtboxNumbers");
```

but it complaints that the "(Textbox)" is a type but its used like a variable and it cant find the Findcontrol method :'(

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF ways to find controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls

This question looks it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcource you cannot. Doing this

```
(TextBox).Findcontrol("txtboxNumbers");
```

You try to invoke method `Findcontrol` on `Type`. Instead try (in window or control *.cs file):

```
TextBox oTextBox = FindName("txtboxNumbers") as TextBox;
```

Comment: whats the namespace for Findcontrol. I cant seem to find it

Answer (score 1):

You can find the control with this.FindControl:

```
    TextBox txt = this.FindControl("txtboxNumbers") as TextBox;

    // check if the control was found
    if(txt != null)
    {
       txt.Text = "whatever you want";
    }
```